# Circular symbolic link in /var/www/

Tags: apache2, symbolic-link

I am running `apache2`.  I am trying to make a symbolic link from my project location to apache's `/var/www/`, where it pulls the files to host.

Inside my project directory `myProject`, I ran:

> sudo ln -s . /var/www/myProject

When I go to `0.0.0.0:90`, it does display the myProject folder in the Index.  However, each time I click myProject, the server circulates back to the original Index.  If I click myProject 3 times, the URL becomes `0.0.0.0:90/myProject/myProject/myProject`, with the Index being the same as just `0.0.0.0:90`

Here is my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

```
<VirtualHost *:90>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried changing the `FollowSymLinks` to `+FollowSymLinks`, no effect.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Apache.

It's the way you made your link.

`ln -s` doesnt evaluate `.` relative to your current directory.  Relative links will always be created to the resulting link file.

It it will create a link to `.` in `/var/www` which will evaluate to a full path of `/var/www/.`

You need to replace the dot with a fully qualified file name

`sudo ln -s /home/me/myProject /var/www/myProject`

**Note**
Just to drop the hint *(as I have a similar setup myself)*:  Don't forget to make sure Apache has read permissions on your project files.  It's easy to forget, but the resulting "403" can make you think its the config that's wrong not the file permissions.

Comment: Thanks, linking the full path worked.  How do I make sure Apache has read permissions?

Comment: Almost certainly too late now, but for posterity... You can find the user apache runs as using `ps -ef | grep apache`.  It's most likely `www-data`.  To check that user has access, try to cat a file as that user.  eg: `sudo -u www-data cat /home/me/myProject/index.html`.  This should print the contents of `index.html` to the command line if permissions are correct.